# StorybookJS - Is there a way to export multiple stories at once in an array, rather than named exports?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

So the typical way to export stories from a file is named exports:

```
export const Basic = Template.bind({});
export const Another = Template.bind({});
```

My use case is that I would like to be able to generate the stories in another file, and export them from the stories file. Something like this:

```
export const stories = getStoriesForTemplate(Template);
```

Where `getStoriesForTemplate` is a function that will manipulate the Template is various ways, and return an array of stories.

Obviously that example doesn't work, and I can't figure out a way of being able to use named exports while intentionally not knowing what `getStoriesForTemplate` is returning. I know something like this would work:

```
export const [Basic, Another] = getStoriesForTemplate(Template);
```

But I would like to try and avoid having to define the stories in this file if possible, so they can change etc without needed to update this file.